# Firebase QuerySnapshot returning null for compounded queries

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For my app, I have implemented a filter option. I use a Firebase `Query` to query using said filters. Here's the implementation:

```
private void loadDestinations() {
    Query query = App.getFirestore().collection("destinations");

    if (mFilters.hasCountry()) {
        query = query.whereEqualTo(Destination.FIELD_COUNTRY, mFilters.getCountry());
    }

    if (mFilters.hasPrice()) {
        query = query.whereEqualTo(Destination.FIELD_PRICE, mFilters.getPrice());
    }

    if (mFilters.hasSortBy()) {
        query = query.orderBy(mFilters.getSortBy(), mFilters.getSortDirection());
    }

    query.addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshots, e) -> {
        if (documentSnapshots != null) {
            if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Snapshots are not null and have value");
                List<Destination> destinationList = documentSnapshots.toObjects(Destination.class);
                mDestinations.setValue(destinationList);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Snapshots are not null but have no value");
                mDestinations.setValue(new ArrayList<>());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Snapshots are NULL!");
            mDestinations.setValue(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    });
}
```

Take a look at the second line where I instantiate the `query` object. I then compound it for every type of filter (country, price, sorting) that was added by the user.

Now this loads perfectly fine if I compound country and price, but as soon as I add the sorting aka `query.orderBy()`, the `documentSnapshots` on line 17 return null. To make it even weirder, the snapshotListener retrieves data TWICE if it was with a compounded query. The first time it logs:

> Snapshots are not null and have value

and then immediately afterward it logs

> Snapshots are NULL!

even though the `loadDestinations()` method was called once (I checked).

I know for certain that this wasn't an issue a month or so ago because that's when I developed this portion and tested it out. Yet now, for reason, it is acting this way. Have there been any drastic changes to the API? Is the code at fault?

**EXTRA:** Say, on line 2, I add another `.whereEqualTo()` like so:

`Query query = App.getFirestore().collection("destinations").whereEqualTo("approved", true);`

The listener would return null values with just one filter added (as opposed to two before). The reason I mention this is because I don't think it's an issue with how the data is sorted but more so the fact that compounded queries don't work. And it, for some reason, retries a second time until it is null. I don't think it's about creating an index either because I already did that a month ago. Plus it would have mentioned as much in the log.

Comment: The builder pattern is a bit hard to parse. Can you reduce the code to the simplest possible query (with only hard-coded values for field names and values) that returns nothing, while you think it should return something? Can you then also show a screenshot of the corresponding document/collection structure that you're querying?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the question with the requested info

Comment: Also can you confirm that, under normal operation, the returned `QuerySnapshot` would never be null? Even if the query found no documents.

Comment: As far as I know there should indeed always be a `QuerySnapshot`. It just may contain no data/results.

Comment: Hmm ok so then it seems to be an issue within Firebase because I am writing to logcat if the returned `QuerySnapshot` is null. And it sure is printing that log. I don't think its the SDK that's at fault since I've been at v11.8.0 since I started the project. Perhaps some change was made internally and now the backend is returning null values? Also, thank you for looking into this!

Comment: You don't seem to be checking or printing out the contents of your error object. Can you do that? I suspect what is happening here is that you're encountering a query that needs to be used alongside a compound index, but you're not getting that message because you're not doing any error checking.

Comment: Welp, this is embarrassing. So it did require a query index! It seems the reason it seemed to work sometimes and not other times was because I had failed to build the index for one specific sort of query. That said I can't explain why the listener looked for values twice though it seems to have gone away for now. Thank you!

Comment: Good catch Todd. Wanna post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is that doing a "equals to" query on one field plus a "sort by" on another field requires your creating a composite index in order to run this query.

Normally, you'd get the URL to create this custom index in the error object, so I would highly recommend checking for, and then logging the contents of the error object.

(And even if that isn't the cause, it's always a good idea to get into the habit of checking your error object anyway. That'll probably help you avoid a bunch of mysterious bugs in the future.)